# Circular geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Consider the tube of radius $a > 0$ around a unit-speed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ $$\sigma (s, \theta) = \gamma (s) + a(\cos \theta \ n(s) + \sin \theta \ b(s))$$

Show that the parameter curves on the tube obtained by fixing the value of $s$ are circular geodesics on $\sigma$.

$$$$

Could you give me some hints how we could show that?

Do we maybe use the fact that any normal section of a surface is a geodesic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see geometrically that the normal at the surface at the point $\sigma(s,\theta)$ is the vector $N_\sigma(s,\theta) = n(s)\cos \theta + b(s)\sin \theta$. If $\alpha(\theta) = \sigma(s_0,\theta)$, then you can check that $\alpha$ is parametrized by arc-length, so it suffices to check that $\alpha''(\theta)$ is parallel to $N_\sigma(s_0,\theta)$ and you're done.

Comment: Parallel to the normal is closely related to perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: Yes, sure. But noticing that the normal is given by that expression, we don't need to compute cross products. :)

Comment: How did you find the formula of the normal at the surface, $N_{\sigma}$ ?

Comment: Just think geometrically. The surface is constructed as following: at each point $\gamma(s)$, we consider the normal plane to the curve at that point. The surface consists of all the unit circles in the normal planes. We know that the normal vector to a unit circle in the plane is given by its position vector. The position vector of the unit circle in the normal plane to $\gamma$ at $\gamma(s)$ is given by $n(s)\cos \theta + b(s)\sin \theta$.

Comment: So, we have that $\tilde{\sigma}(\theta)=\sigma (s_0, \theta)$, $$\tilde{\sigma}''=a\left (-\cos\theta \ n(s_0)-\sin\theta \ b(s_0)\right )$$ Therefore $\tilde{\sigma}''\cdot N_{\sigma}=-a$, right? Does this mean that $\tilde{\sigma}''$ is parallel to $N_{\sigma}$ ?

Comment: You conclude that they are parallel not because $\widetilde{\sigma}''\cdot N_\sigma = -a$, but because $\widetilde{\sigma}''(\theta) = -a N_\sigma(s_0, \theta)$.

Comment: So, from that we have that $\tilde{\sigma}$ is a geodesic, right? But why is it a **circular** geodesic?

Comment: @Mary Because each $\widetilde{\sigma}$ is actually a circle with center $\gamma(s_0)$ and radius $a$, in the normal plane spanned by $n(s_0)$ and $b(s_0)$.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: Glad to help! ${}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** In general, if $\sigma'\times\left(\sigma'\times\sigma''\right)$ is perpendicular to the surface, then $\sigma$ is a geodesic. However, for a constant speed curve, we only need that $\sigma''$ is perpendicular to the surface since
$$
a\times(a\times b)=\frac{b\cdot a}{a\cdot a}\,a-b
$$
and $\sigma'\cdot\sigma''=0$ for a constant speed curve.

---

**From Comments:** Two surface tangents are
$$
\partial_s\sigma=t+a(\cos(\theta)\,n'+\sin(\theta)\,t\times n')\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\tilde\sigma'=\partial_\theta\sigma=a(-\sin(\theta)n+\cos(\theta)t\times n)\tag{2}
$$
Since
$$
\tilde\sigma''=\partial_\theta^2\sigma=-a(\cos(\theta)n+\sin(\theta)t\times n)\tag{3}
$$
is perpendicular to both, it is perpendicular to the surface. Therefore, $\tilde\sigma$ is a geodesic for each $s$.

Comment: So we have $$\tilde{\sigma}(\theta)=\sigma (s_0, \theta)$$ Do we have to show that $\tilde{\sigma}'\times (\tilde{\sigma}'\times\tilde{\sigma}'')$ is perpendicular to the surface?

Comment: Since this is a constant speed curve, we only need to show that $\tilde\sigma''$ is perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: We have that $$\tilde{\sigma}'(\theta)=\frac{d}{d\theta}\sigma  (s_0, \theta) = a(-\sin \theta \ n(s) + \cos \theta \ b(s)) \Rightarrow \|\tilde{\sigma}'\|^2=\|a(-\sin \theta \ n(s) + \cos \theta \ b(s))\|^2=a^2=\text{ constant } $$ right ? To show that $\tilde{\sigma}''$ is perpendicular to the surface do we have to show that $\tilde{\sigma}''\cdot \sigma=0$ ?

Comment: Or isn't $\tilde{\sigma}''\cdot \sigma=0$ the condition that should be satisfied?

Comment: Two surface tangents are $(t+a(\cos(\theta)\,n'+\sin(\theta)\,t\times n'))$ and $a(-\sin(\theta)n+\cos(\theta)t\times n)$. Since $\sigma''=-a(\cos(\theta)\,n+\sin(\theta)\,t\times n)$ is perpendicular to both, it is perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: I see... So, from that we have that $\tilde{\sigma}$ is a geodesic, right? But why is it a **circular** geodesic?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. It is a geodesic and it is circular.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Any curve of intersection produced by normal section of this argument cannot or should not be used for arriving at the result. One special case is a sphere cut along any great circle.

Comment: Is a sphere cut along any great circle a special case where we can use that?

Comment: When tube and sphere have a common normal, yes.

Comment: Ok... Thanks!! :-)